# Java 8 - distinct on stream of Strings - IllegalStateException

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem with distinct action on `stream` of `String`'s.

```
Stream<String> names = Arrays.asList("NAME A", "NAME B", "NAME A").stream();
names.distinct();
System.out.println(names.collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Then, I received exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.Test.main(Test.java:62)
```

But if I write this part of code like this:

```
Stream<String> names = Arrays.asList("NAME A", "NAME B", "NAME A").stream();
final Stream<String> distinct = names.distinct();
System.out.println(distinct.collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Everything is OK.

Documentation of distinct says:

> Stream distinct()
>   Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.
>   For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter order is preserved.) For unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made.
>   This is a stateful intermediate operation.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help

Comment: @choasia, please read carefully

Comment: Isn't it because you ignored new stream generated by an intermediate operation and one stream can be operated only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation and error message give you the reason:`stream has already been operated upon or closed` and `distinct() Returns a stream`

When you call `distinct` on `names`, it *returns* a new stream with distinct elements. But then you `collect` on  `names` again. But this stream was already consumed by the `distinct` operator.

In your second example you to it correctly, because you collect the distinct stream.

So basically, you always have to do it like in your second example, or in short

```
names.distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically you're using the stream API wrong.

You're ignoring the return value of `distinct()` which you shouldn't be doing. It's similar to any method that doesn't operate directly on the parameter, but returns a modified version of it.

The idiomatic version would be

```
String names = Arrays.asList("NAME A", "NAME B", "NAME A").
    stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(",");
System.out.println(names);
```

Answer (score 4):

As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) says:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw `IllegalStateException` if it detects that the stream is being reused.

So once you’ve called `distinct()` on a stream, you must not use it again. Instead, use the returned stream. When you chain the operations in the form `source.stream().intermediateOp().anotherIntermediateOp().terminalOp()`, this error can never arise.

---

So in your case, it would be

```
String s = Arrays.asList("NAME A", "NAME B", "NAME A").stream()
         .distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(s);
```

but you can use the straight-forward

```
String s = Stream.of("NAME A", "NAME B", "NAME A")
         .distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(s);
```

instead of using `Arrays.asList`.